# Tool for Modifying Picklist Values

Tags: apex, picklist, appexchange

Is there any tool available for exporting/importing/updating/deleting picklist values ?
I checked whether it is possible to do via data loader and unfortunately I found that i could not do that...:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Data Loader can't do this. It only works on "data," while picklist values are a type of "metadata." There is a tool called the Migration Tool, which you can find in Setup > Develop > Tools > Force.com Migration Tool, or the approximately equivalent Force.com IDE (located under Tools, as well). However, even this tool isn't straight-forward-- it requires a level of comfort editing XML files. As long as you understand XML, and you're comfortable with editing those files, you might take a look at these tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following link of the AppExchange Package: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000018leZEAQ

Force.com developer tool to view and extract object metadata details. Don't waste time clicking through multiple screens to lookup recordtypes, field types, picklists, and other metadata. EasyDescribe it and get everything at once!